# Problem with Blossoms while searching for augmenting pathes

Tags: graphs, matching

I have problems understanding the effect of Blossoms while searching for augmenting pathes (in the matching problem).
If I have the following graph

[image: Graph]

Can't I find the augmented path from n1 to n13?

Isn't DFS as well as BFS always able to find the augmented path?
If I understand correctly, because of the Blossoms there should be at least one BFS/DFS tree, which cannot reach n13, is that correct?

Comment: You will find the augmented path from $n1$ to $n13$ by using DFS/BFS. By the way, $n13$ should be $n14$ as you missed to label one vertex. After augmenting the path you end up with a perfect matching of 7 edges.

Comment: Thanks HueHang; Oh, you're right. I took the image from a script and labelled it afterwards. Well, then the script is wrong in blaming this would not necessarily be found.